# Change draggable marker cursor on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

When creating a new market I use 'cursor' parameter to set a cursor type on this market, but if the draggable parameter is set to true I'm unable to change the cursor. It's always 'pointer'. Here is my code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map:map,
                draggable:true,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: center,
                cursor: 'move'
            });
```

So, if the `draggable` isn't set to `true` the cursor of the marker is `'move'` but if it's true, then it becomes `'pointer'`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that has been around for a while https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3120